# View Controller Transfer

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, reload, rootviewcontroller

I've run into an error with my code. I currently have a reachability status that monitors my internet connection. If the user loses internet connection and then regains it the root view controller is presented. I would like it that the user's current view controller is maintained.

I'm unsure if this is because my MGLMapView is forcing a reload somehow? Please, can someone tell me how to stop the screen transfer?

My reachability status code is this:

```
let ReachabilityStatusChangedNotification = "ReachabilityStatusChangedNotification"

enum ReachabilityType: CustomStringConvertible {
case wwan
case wiFi

var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .wwan: return "WWAN"
    case .wiFi: return "WiFi"
    }
}
}

enum ReachabilityStatus: CustomStringConvertible  {
case offline
case online(ReachabilityType)
case unknown

var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .offline: return "Offline"
    case .online(let type): return "Online (\(type))"
    case .unknown: return "Unknown"
    }
}
}

public class Reach {

func connectionStatus() -> ReachabilityStatus {
    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return .unknown
    }

    var flags : SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return .unknown
    }

    return ReachabilityStatus(reachabilityFlags: flags)
}


func monitorReachabilityChanges() {
    let host = "google.com"
    var context = SCNetworkReachabilityContext(version: 0, info: nil, retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
    let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(nil, host)!

    SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachability, { (_, flags, _) in
        let status = ReachabilityStatus(reachabilityFlags: flags)

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: ReachabilityStatusChangedNotification),
                                        object: nil,
                                        userInfo: ["Status": status.description])

    }, &context)

    SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(reachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), RunLoop.Mode.common as CFString)
}

}

extension ReachabilityStatus {
init(reachabilityFlags flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) {
    let connectionRequired = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let isWWAN = flags.contains(.isWWAN)

    if !connectionRequired && isReachable {
        if isWWAN {
            self = .online(.wwan)
        } else {
            self = .online(.wiFi)
        }
    } else {
        self =  .offline
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Check to see what you're doing when the Notification is posted.

Comment: The notification is posted in viewDidLoad, after setting up the basics of the map. Like Delegate, User Follow Mode and mapView Style. @Don